# I have to move homes, so my Bitcoin/Lightning node will be offline for around 1 day

Tags: lightning-network, full-node

I have to move homes, so my Bitcoin/Lightning node will be offline for around 1 day.
What happens in this case to my Lightning channel? Will I be penalised for being offline by the system? How should I deal with this?

Answer (score 3):

You have to make sure that the channels you opened have sufficient time locks that your partners can't make an attempt to cheat you. (Even if your timelocks are less than a day your partners might not try to cheat on you as they will not know that it is less than a day)

next you just turn off your node which sends out gossip messages to the network. you relocate and you turn your node on again. The protocol does not care about your uptime and penalise you. However there might be some nodes that try to monitor uptime and penilise you. But the individual behavior of participants is beyond the scope of our knowledge

Comment: Thanks Rene! You're a star.